# Android: Dex Issue(UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:)

Tags: java, android, dex, android-multidex

> My app is showing error while compiling when i use these 3 jar files:
>
> Activation.jar   mail.jar    additionnal.jar
>
> I Need these jar files to send email without user intervention.
>
> I am getting following error:
>   **UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2**
>
> I cant use multidex enabled as true and extends MultiDexActivity in my
>   main file as i am using AppCombat Activity in my app.
>
> My Gradle file looks like this:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>         compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
>     compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'ParseCrashReporting-*.jar')
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'additionnal.jar')
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'mail.jar')
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'activation.jar')
>     compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
>     compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
>     compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
>     compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+'
>     compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
>     compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
>     compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
>     compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
>     compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
>     compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
>     compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.0'
>     compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
>     compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.3'
>
> }
> ```

Comment: MultiDexActivity? What is that? To use multidex you can extend your Application class with MultiDexApplication. But you don't have to. There's an option to just call MultiDex#install in your Application#attachBaseContext method. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html and http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use MultiDex for some reasons, why not trying [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/optimizations.html)
to optimize your code? As I know, it can also perform optimizations at the bytecode level, inside and across methods, inline private methods to reduce amount of them, so you'll be able to avoid this 65k limit. For more details on configuration you may wanna look [here](http://blog.androidquery.com/2011/06/android-optimization-with-proper.html).